# Найти наибольшее количество бонусных очков

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Алгоритм для задачи (двумерный тетрис).

> Условие: Есть матрица K*N, изначально она заполненна цветами (числами от 0 до 5), 0 - пустая клетка, 1-5 - цвета. В верхнем левом углу вертикальная фигурка размером 3*1. Раскрашенная произвольно в 3 цвета. Можно сдвигать вправо, а так же циклически менять цвета (все делается мгновенно). Как только фигура упала, смортим если совпадают 3 ячейкии одного цвета, то все мгновенно исчезает, и все фигурки слетают вниз и т.д. пока все не остановится.

Спрашивается, какое максимальное кол-во бонусов можно найти. Но у меня вопрос, вот упала фигура и как теперь сосчитать все бонусы? Перезаписывать матрицы со смещением?

Comment: Продвинутый тетрис?)
Выложи код)

Answer (score 1):

Как только фигура упала, проверяешь наличие совпадений, если совпадения есть, то их уничтожаемшь и все висящие фигуры опускаешь, и опять проверяешь наличие 3 и более цветов, и так до тех пор пока есть 3 и более цветов.